# how to get a turtle to check a patch set

Tags: netlogo

i have a set of turtles that i'm aiming to check a patch set, and if there is any stationary turtles on that set of patches i want that original turtle to stop, 
essentially a box junction situation.

i have tried by setting the meaning of the patches as a crossroad and attempting to make a check crossroad function

cross roads are made by:

```
;create crossroads
ask patches with [(
pxcor mod 40 = 31 or pxcor mod 40 = 32 or pxcor mod 40 = 33 or pxcor mod 40 = 34 or pxcor mod 40 = 35 or pxcor mod 40 = 36 or pxcor mod 40 = 37 or pxcor mod 40 = 38 or pxcor mod 40 = 39 or pxcor mod 40 = 0 or pxcor mod 40 = 1 or pxcor mod 40 = 2 or pxcor mod 40 = 3 or pxcor mod 40 = 4 or pxcor mod 40 = 5)
and (
pycor mod 44 = 35 or pycor mod 44 = 36 or pycor mod 44 = 37 or pycor mod 44 = 38 or pycor mod 44 = 39 or pycor mod 44 = 40 or pycor mod 44 = 41 or pycor mod 44 = 42 or pycor mod 44 = 43 or pycor mod 44 = 0 or pycor mod 44 = 1 or pycor mod 44 = 2 or pycor mod 44 = 3 or pycor mod 4 = 4 or pycor mod 44 = 5)] [
set pcolor grey
 set meaning "crossroad"
]
```

i've also tried making it check patches in front of it with a patch set but i cant get it to work

```
to check-crossroad
let in-crossroad (patch-set patch-ahead 8 patch-ahead 7 patch-ahead 6 patch-ahead 5 patch-ahead 4 patch-ahead 3 patch-ahead 2 patch-ahead 1 patch-left-and-ahead 26 3 patch-right-and-ahead 26 3 )
let car3-oncrossroad one-of cars3-on in-crossroad

if [meaning] of patch-ahead 4 = "crossroad" and will-stop? = "maybe"
if [used] of patch-set in-crossroad and will-stop? = "yes"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It might work to have turtles check if any other turtles are present on the junction using `member?`, then being free to move into the junction if not. Using this setup:

```
globals [ box-to-check ]

to setup
  ca
  set box-to-check patches with [
    pxcor > -3 and pxcor < 3 and
    pycor > -3 and pycor < 3 
  ]
  ask box-to-check [
    set pcolor grey - 2
  ]
  crt 10 [ 
    setxy ( random 15 - 20 ) one-of [ -1 0 1 ]
    set heading 90
  ]
  crt 10 [ 
    setxy one-of [ -1 0 1 ] ( random 15 - 20 )
    set heading 0
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Use these reporters for your junction checking and a basic move procedure for good measure:

```
to-report other-turtles-on-junction
  let o-turtles other turtles with [ member? patch-here box-to-check ]
  report o-turtles 
end

to move
  if not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [
    move-to patch-ahead 1
  ]
end
```

Then just have your turtles check that reporter any time they're about to move into the junction:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    ifelse member? patch-ahead 1 box-to-check [
      if not any? other-turtles-on-junction [
        move
      ]
    ] [
      move
    ]
  ]
  tick   
end
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas, but keep in mind you'll need to fiddle to accommodate for things like multiple junctions etc.